# How to enable/disable Spring Memcache (Azure OR AWS) based on configuration

Tags: java, spring, memcached

In one of our product we are using Spring ver. 4 framework.  This product is hosted on Azure or AWS based on customer's preference.  We would like to enable memcache for better performance.

Our desired configuration will be :

- applicationContext.xml which will include cacheConfig.xml

This cacheConfig.xml (which may include a property file), should specify :

- Is cache enabled OR disabled
- Cache Provider.

I checked about spring simple memcache lib., which supports AWS Memcache.

We did couple of POC but all of them suggests change in code or use maven profile.
But not much luck.

I hope we are moving in right direction.  Any comment/answer is most welcomed!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "We did couple of POC but all of them suggests change in code or use maven profile. But not much luck.". It has nothing to do with luck. Is there a reason you can't use maven profiles (and/or spring profiles)?

Comment: @Kayaman we have 3 env. QA-Staging->Prod
On team want to disable cache on QA but want to keep on Staging and Prod
We dont want to compile package for each env. Basically once code is compiled and release is packaged, same should be moved to prod if things are OK!! (our integration and deployment is automated)

Comment: @Kayaman check my comment again pls

Comment: You can use Spring profiles to enable or disable things. No recompilation is needed. For compile differences, if needed, you can use maven profiles. You can even use both of them together.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable caching with configuration property `spring.cache.type=none`. You could check out [Memcached Spring Boot](https://github.com/sixhours-team/memcached-spring-boot) library which provides implementation for the Spring Cache Abstraction.